# Where to store media uploaded by the plugin?

Tags: plugins, uploads, media

Is there a convention on how to store media uploaded and used only by the plugin? Would that be `/wp-content/uploads/plugin_name` or should they be stored like the rest of the media (chronogically)? Especially if there will be a lot of images that could be categorised in folders easily (eg. `plugin_name/players`, `plugin_name/clubs`)?

If the answer is creating an own plugin folder in `uploads`, how would you approach changing the upload directory for media uploaded in plugin's admin page?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to create your own plugin upload folder in `/wp-content/uploads` the following code will basically create a custom folder inside uploads called `myplugin_uploads` and put an empty `index.html` inside it.

#### Dynamically creating your custom upload folder

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_files' );
function create_files() {

    $upload_dir      = wp_upload_dir();

    $files = array(
        array(
            'base'      => $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/myplugin_uploads',
            'file'      => 'index.html',
            'content'   => ''
        )
    );

    foreach ( $files as $file ) {
        if ( wp_mkdir_p( $file['base'] ) && ! file_exists( trailingslashit( $file['base'] ) . $file['file'] ) ) {
            if ( $file_handle = @fopen( trailingslashit( $file['base'] ) . $file['file'], 'w' ) ) {
                fwrite( $file_handle, $file['content'] );
                fclose( $file_handle );
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Now practically, you'll need to change the upload dir/destination. You can do so using the [upload_dir](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/upload_dir) filter hook.

#### Example

```
add_filter('upload_dir', 'myplugin_upload_dir');
function myplugin_upload_dir( $param ){
    $mydir = '/myplugin_uploads';

    $param['path'] = $param['path'] . $mydir;
    $param['url'] = $param['url'] . $mydir;

    return $param;
}
```

When you're done you can remove the filter with code:

```
remove_filter('upload_dir', 'myplugin_upload_dir');
```